# Is there a primitive type for audio?

Tags: bixby

Currently have a result view that displaying a list of audio title while playing audios, would like to change to another playlist by on-click on the list. So in my mind, i would pass the audioInfo to the action that play audio, relaunch a new playlist.

```
on-click{
    intent{
        goal: playNews
        value: audio.AudioInfo(this)
    }
}
```

But audio.AudioInfo is not a primitive type. Would love to ask is there a primitive type for audioInfo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [our online DOC](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/library.audio), the audio.AudioInfo is a structure.

It is just matter of syntax when doing `intent`. The way you are using is usually giving a predefine primitive value at compile time, like the following.

```
intent {
 goal: FindAge
 value: IntAge(18)
}
```

To fix your code, do the following, and you can read more about the syntax here in [our online DOC](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/customizing-plan.using-el#el-in-bixby-language).

```
on-click{
    intent{
        goal: playNews
        value: $expr(this)
    }
}
```

In fact, I would recommend the later syntax even for primitive types as long as the value pass in is not a constant defined at compile time.